# `\` at end of line of a code merges lines when editing

Tags: bug, editor

I was attempting to edit [an answer on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics/1471#1471). The answer contains the following piece of code:

```
SOURCE=$1
for name in $( \
    grep '^[:space:]*\\beginpgfgraphicnamed' $SOURCE | \
    sed s'/[:space:]*\\beginpgfgraphicnamed{\(.*\)}/\1/' \
); do
    pdflatex --jobname=$name $SOURCE
done
```

When clicking the “edit” link button below the answer, I’m presented with the following Markdown markup:

```
[…]

    SOURCE=$1
    for name in $(         grep '^[:space:]*\\beginpgfgraphicnamed' $SOURCE |         sed s'/[:space:]*\\beginpgfgraphicnamed{\(.*\)}/\1/'     ); do
        pdflatex --jobname=$name $SOURCE
    done

[…]
```

Clearly, the `\` line continuations in the Bash script have been interpreted by some part of the editor(?) code, and the lines have been merged.